# Probability of the file being lost

Tags: probability, reliability

A file is split into $M$ parts and stored at $N$ nodes: the 1st part (of the first copy of the file) stored on node $1$, the second on node $2$ and so on, wrapping circularly. Each part of file has $K$ copies stored on these nodes (e.g. the same as the first copy but rotating the tuple of nodes to one node for the second copy, rotating (wrapping circularly) to two nodes for the third part, etc.)

The probability of node failure is $q$. What is the probability that the entire file can be restored (we assume node failure erases all the file parts stored on it).

---

My attempt to solve:

Probability of a copy of a shard to be damaged: $q^{1 / K}$.

Probability of a shard to be damaged: $q^{N / K}$.

Probability that a file goes well: $1 - (1 - q)^{N / K}$.

Also, can you propose more reliable strategy of storage on $N$ nodes than mine?

Comment: I cannot understand your description of the storage scheme - particularly the "e.g." statement, which obfuscates instead clarifying. More generally, I see nothing to be gained by breaking the file into $M$ parts. Just put the full file on $K$ nodes. You lose the file if and only if that set of $K$ nodes all fail. But if you break the file into $M$ parts, then, instead of one set of $K$ nodes that will lose the file, you have $M$ such sets of $K$ nodes, any one of which if all lost will result in loss of the file.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The file is broken into parts for the case if it is a big file and a node has not enough free storage for it.

Comment: Which statement leaves even more confused about this scheme. If the node is filled, you cannot store other pieces of the file on it, so what is this "wrapping circularly" concept at all? I would say if you can't fit the file on a single node, you should still make $M$ as small as possible.

Comment: @PaulSinclair We cannot make M as small as possible, because we need to be "fair" trying not to give a node "unfair disadvantage" of much data stored in it, while other nodes remain with little our data.

Comment: Why? Are you afraid that the inequality will cause them anxiety? As I've already pointed out, the higher $M$ is, the more opportunities you provide for a group of $K$ failures to leave you with unrecoverable data. It seems to me that you have grabbed onto a bad idea, and are so sure of it that even when the problem is pointed out, you refuse to reconsider.